# SimpleDateFormat behaviour

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have the following lines:

```
final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse("2004-52-05");
```

I expect that an exception will be thrown in line 2, because '52' is not a valid month, but code runs and the date stored in d object is

```
Sat Apr 05 00:00:00 EEST 2008
```

Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: I'm sure that the reason this is happening is because it's being set to 52 months, which would be April 2008 (4 years 4 months). Why it's not erroring someone else can answer.

Comment: @Hiru Better explanation than mine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If you want to create a date object that strictly matches your
>   pattern, then set lenient to false.

From Javadoc

> Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient
>   and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a
>   wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar
>   recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the
>   calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient
>   GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as
>   February 1.

Refer this for more information [**lenitent**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#isLenient%28%29)

So add this..

```
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
```

This will throw an `Exception` as you were Expecting..

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2004-52-05"
```